# Flexible Grid where each item is the same height and width

Tags: html, css

I am writing a front page grid for a small website.

The grid will have six items. Each item will contain a headline, an icon, and a few sentences of text.

- At high resolutions, the grid should display as 3x2
- At medium resolutions, the grid should display as 2x3
- At low resolutions, the grid should display as 1x6
- Any items in the same row should be the same height (it is OK if different rows have different heights).

I have accomplished something very close using `inline-block` sections that have a % width and a minimum-width, example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/obhc7fep/1/

However, when two neighbor divs have different length text inside them, the "shorter" neighbor does not grow to the available vertical space. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

What is the best way to get "neighbor" divs to stay the same height, when it is not possible to wrap them in a "row" div because you don't know how many items will be in a row at time of code generation?

Comment: Could someone please explain the closing?  I have no idea how to make the question more focused. It looks a certain way, I want it to look a specific other way.  That is extremely focused.

Answer (score 1):

This could help:

```
#frontPageGrid {
  display:flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

see : https://jsfiddle.net/g84xajwu/